# Is it possible to start SQL Server Managment Studio from Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I want to use SQL Server Managment Studio (on windows 11) without installing it. Is It possible to start this application from docker image?

I can not find info if is possible to start SSMS (Managment Studio) also form docker image on windows.

I want to use SSMS on my win11 machine without installing it (via docker). Is it possible?

Comment: SSMS is a Windows application. The `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` Docker images are SQL Server for Linux installed on Ubuntu. Why would you be able to launch SSMS from them?

Comment: No, you can't start SSMS from Docker as there is no Linux version of it. The closest (Microsoft) tool that has a native Linux version would be Azure Data Studio.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is a separate client application used for managing SQL Server databases and is not included in the Microsoft SQL Server Docker image. The Docker image you mentioned is specifically for running SQL Server in a containerized environment.

Comment: `without installing it` why? Is there an actual reason or "just in case"? Docker and containers aren't used to deploy *desktop* applications to begin with because the applications have to coordinate with the OS itself to draw on the computer's screen. There are ways to virtualize applications so they can be applied to restricted desktops or follow users across machines, but SSMS is a DBA tool, not something you run on a restricted account.

Comment: You can install Azure Data Studio or even Chrome in WSL though, run it inside WSL and work with it on the Windows desktop.